# How to create checkboxes in Dropdown list in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, checkbox

Is there a way I can create a dropdown list in Excel 2010 which has checkboxes, so that I can select multiple items from the dropdown ?

Answer (score 0):

Make it a listbox and set the MultiSelect parameter to fmMultiSelectExtended or fmMultiSelectMulti. It won't be a dropdown, but it's your best bet.